# How can I remove white border around my footer although I reset all default stylings in Opera Browser

Tags: html, css, frontend

I know to get rid of white borders I need to globally reset default stylings but I did it already and didn't work , it's actually working on chrome but not opera , I'm still getting white borders around my footer even with same background color with my main , here's my codes :

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

 :root {
  --clr-bg: #170D4F;
  --clr-bg-light: #4C3881;
  --clr-bg-lighter: #F8EBFF;
  --clr-accent: #00C9A3;
  --clr-bright: #FAFAFA;
  --ft-accent: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
  --ft-primary: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.mylogo {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

header {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
  display: flex;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: var(--ft-accent);
}

nav {
  width: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5rem;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

main {
  background: darkblue;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-clip: content-box;
  font-family: var(--ft-primary);
  text-shadow: 3px 3px black;
  color: var(--clr-bg-lighter);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mymail {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}

.mytel {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: var(--ft-accent);
  background-color: var(--clr-bg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/main.css">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="/src/logo.png" alt="site-logo" class="mylogo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>About</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h1>Hi I'm John<span style="color: #00c9a3;">y</span></h1>
    <h2>I'm Front-End Webprogrammer</h2>
    <h3>and I'm Passionate to learn new things</h3>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>How to contact me ? from there : </p>
    <div class="contact-container">
      <img src="/src/email.svg" alt="contact via email" class="mymail">
      <img src="/src/telephone-handle-silhouette.svg" alt="contact via Telephone" class="mytel">
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

and here's the result and that weird white border :

[image]

note: footer is not completed yet because of that it's not pretty , don't kill me because of this!

Comment: I tried reproducing it, But I can't see any border. In which browser you're viewing this, Can you try any other browsers?

Comment: @Sameer oh jeez ! I'm using opera , now I tried edge and it is working ! why?!

Comment: @Sameer opera is chromium base too

Comment: I think you typed `width` instead of `margin` in the footer (`width: 0 auto`).

Comment: @gvdltubdlpwfsgmpx Every browser has its own [user agent's default styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#user-agent_stylesheets), Unfortunately, I don't have an opera browser to test, Hope someone helps you.

Comment: Your snippet includes external images and other content that could be responsible. Please post something that actually reproduces the problem first.

Comment: @Dai this is just proxy , it's not actual resume or actual person , I'm doing it for practice and I posted codes too , the problem is that narrow white border in footer section in the picture

Comment: @gvdltubdlpwfsgmpx Yes, but that's not the problem. The problem is that the issue does not reproduce in the snippet you posted to StackOverflow. Can you at least reproduce it on CodePen or JSFiddle or similar?